# HeadTransform variables produce bad data ex: 0, 0, 0, 1

Tags: java, android, google-cardboard

Here is my code (I added this code to the google cardboard sample):

```
float[] headpos;

headpos =  new float[4];

HeadTransform headTransform1 = new HeadTransform();

headTransform1.getQuaternion(headpos, 0);

Log.d("Rotation Data", java.util.Arrays.toString(headpos));
```

This produces bad data as I exampled above, No matter what get command I use, Such as getHeadview. Where as it works perfectly when I use the original headTransform, I have tested it with my headpos variable to confirm that it isn't my variable that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple really. You create a new object, dont do anything to it and read it's state. The state will simply be the initial state. That includes having a rotation quaternion of 0,0,0,1.